# Proper way to integrate JS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I want to include a JS library in my Angular app. I have searched for this and I found many approaches. In my case I will include this https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/ library. My expectation was that I can create a module e.g. 'plot-function' that provides a function tag that takes the options the library needed.

As example:

```html
<div class="somediv">
    <ng-function [options]="options" [function]="function"></ng-function>
</div>
```

But I can't find an approache that will work like this. 
Do you have any ideas, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few considerations & different answers depending on what kind of library you are trying to integrate...

1. **The library is an NPM module**

If so, import it in to your code using the most up-to-date module
syntax the library supports - [ideally using some kind of ES6/TypeScript import syntax covered here](https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/06/typescript-and-es6-import-syntax/). If the library doesn't support one of these modern import syntaxes, you can still use ES5 require syntax:

```
const myModule = require('myModule');
```

2. **The library is not an NPM module**

[See this official guide](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries)